# Terminating app due to uncaught exception "NSInvalideArgumentException"

Tags: uitableview

I have my custom class Users which have several fields. e.g. username, password, first name, last name.

i have an object of Users class user. when i want to set the text of UILabel of UITableviewCell it giving me the following exception:

Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFDictionary firstName]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x755f510'

my code is:

```
self.user = [usersArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

((UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:19]).text = user.firstName;
((UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:20]).text = user.lastName;
((UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:21]).text = user.username;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have done it by using NSDictionary. I passed the object of my custom class to NSDictionary and then set the text of UITableviewCell through NSDictionary.

```
NSDictionary *dictionary = (NSDictionary *)[usersArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

((UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:19]).text = [dictionary objectForKey:@"firstName"];
((UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:20]).text = [dictionary objectForKey:@"firstName"];
((UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:21]).text = [dictionary objectForKey:@"firstName"];
```